# Cannot select a particular dropdown control with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm having difficulty selecting a particular dropdown on my webpage with Selenium IDE. The html code of the dropdown is the following:

```
<tr>
 <td class="lbl">Change Reason:</td>
  <td class="fld">
   <select class="foggy w162px" onchange="setOtherFieldAvailability(this);" name="drpReason">
    <option value="New Information">New Information</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="Changed Data">Changed Data</option>
    <option value="Transcription Error">Transcription Error</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
 </td>
</tr>
```

The functionality of this control is perfectly fine. But Selenium IDE can't seem to select it. The Selenum command line is the following:

```
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>name=drpReason</td>
    <td>value=Other</td>
</tr>
```

I receive the following error message:

**[error] Specified element is not a Select (has no options)**

I then try to verify the text of the dropdown with the following:

```
<tr>
    <td>assertText</td>
    <td>name=drpReason</td>
    <td>New Information Changed Data Transcription Error Other</td>
</tr>
```

I receive the following error message:

**[error] Actual value '' did not match 'New Information Changed Data Transcription Error Other'**

I don't understand what is going on. Any help would be appreciated.

Ilya

Comment: try to use not select, but clickAt - `clickAt("css=select[name=drpReason] option[value=Other]");` But you know, you should click the dropdown menu to expand it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. We figured it out. The field was hidden, as it turns out.